# Salesforce Connector - Username-Password Authentication

Tags: ballerina

Does `salesforce:ConnectionConfig` supports username - password authentication?

Answer (score 0):

`OAuth2RefreshTokenGrantConfig` and `BearerTokenConfig` are supported in `salesforce:ConnectionConfig` of ballerinax-sfdc module.
We can find more information on  https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/salesforce/latest#ConnectionConfig